# How separate one js file into multiple js file?

Tags: javascript

My javascript file structure is given below. I want to separate this file into a.js, b.js, c.js. How it is possible ?

```
var app = (function () {
   'use strict';

    var a = {

    }
    var b = {
          setup: function () {

          }
    }
    var c = {

    }

    function d() {

    }
    return {
        initialize: function () {
            b.setup();
            d();
        }

    };
});

app().d();
```

Comment: you might need to use some library when you can inject dependency for example RequireJS

Answer (score -1):

In HTML, you can import other files using the following syntax

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
```

and in Node.js, you can use the `reuire()` function. However, you might need to look into using `exports.module = ...` syntax in your `a.js` file.

Then, in your main file you can do

`var a = require("a.js")`